# how to access magento site through API key by android platform

Tags: api, app

We want to know information about **API key** in **magento**

We are planning to develop an android app for our magento site. So we want some information about how we can do that.

Along with that how to get information about magento site through API key

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first implement the magento api module for your android api based on your requirement of required request and response.

You can then create a Role and User for your app at ‘System - - > Web Services’ in admin side. You need to create XMLRPC role and user for your app.
You can then login into your app by these three parameters: 1) Store URL, 2) Username and 3) Password.

You may also refer our likewise apps at https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Indies%20Apps&hl=en

Let me know if you need any other assistance.